# doing too many write operations in django rest framework and postgres

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I have this excel sheet where i can have as many as 3000-5000 or may be more data( email ids) and i need to insert each of these into my db one by one .I have been asked not to make these many write operations in one go .How should i go about solving this so that i don't do so many entries to database  ?Any hint will be highly appreciated .
The solution i could think of is this .
https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2019/01/09/django-bulk-inserts/

Comment: Show us some of your current code, please.

Comment: "I have been asked not to make these many write operations in one go"  Why?  Without knowing the rationale for that request, we don't know the best way to address it.  If your boss issues edicts without explanations, then you should be asking him, not us, for how to work around them.

Answer (score 2):

I'd vote for doing bulk operations withithe django model itself 
you can for example do the following with your model class :

```
... Entry.objects.bulk_create([
...     Entry(headline='This is a test'),
...     Entry(headline='This is only a test'),
... ])
```

(code from django website)

you can also you transaction dicorator were you can in sure that a database trasaction is atomic (All or Nothing), thisis handy when you want to do long processeing for your entities or transform them

```
from django.db import transaction

@transaction.atomic
```

decorate your method that inserts records into the database

Answer (score 0):

I think that the link you included would work fairly well!

Just wanted to throw one other option out there. Many databases have batch/bulk upload capabilities. Depending on what DB you're using, you could potentially connect directly to it, and perform your writes without Django.